# My UserControl's TextBlock binding doesn't update even once

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp

I know this has been asked for many times. I read a lot of them and tried different ways but still could not get it to work.

The xaml code is a UserControl:

```
<Grid Name="middle">
    <d:TextBlock Text="{x:Bind LayerNodeData.CleanName, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="WhiteSmoke" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Arial" VerticalAlignment="Center" RelativePanel.RightOf="visibleUI" DoubleTapped="OnEditNameBegin" />
</Grid>
```

I set both this.DataContext and the Grid's DataContext to the data instance.

c#

```
public ucLayerRow(ImageLayerNode data)
{
        LayerNodeData = data;

        DataContext = LayerNodeData;

        this.InitializeComponent();

        middle.DataContext = LayerNodeData;

        LayerNodeData.NotifyPropertyChanged("CleanName"); // test if it work

        RefreshUI();
}
```

Model class

```
public partial class ImageLayerNode : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            // PropertyChanged is always null.
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
        
    public string mCleanName = string.Empty;
    public string CleanName { 
        get => mCleanName;
        set { mCleanName = value; NotifyPropertyChanged();}
    }
    ....
}
```

I tried add a breakpoint to the PropertyChanged and found that it is always null and thus never get called. I also tried changing the mode to OneWay, TwoWays but still nothing.

The textblock is away empty not even getting a value once.

The user control is added like this to the main page. Not sure if it is related.

```
var rowUI = new ucLayerRow(layerNode);                        
layerContainer.Children.Add(rowUI);
```

Comment: Where do you declare `LayerNodeData` property ?

Comment: And why you use design time `d:`? please try to remove 'd:'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My UserControl's TextBlock binding doesn't update even once

During the testing, the problem looks that you use [design time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/displaying-data-in-the-designer) for usercontrol. `<d:TextBlock/>` please remove `d:` and make your usercontrol like the following.

Xaml

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        FontFamily="Arial"
        FontSize="12"
        Foreground="Red"
        Text="{x:Bind LayerNodeData.CleanName, Mode=OneWay}" />
</Grid>
```

**Code behind**

```
public sealed partial class ucLayerRow : UserControl
{
    public ucLayerRow(ImageLayerNode data)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        LayerNodeData = data;
    }
 
    public ImageLayerNode LayerNodeData { get; set; }
}
public partial class ImageLayerNode : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            // PropertyChanged is always null.
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private string mCleanName = string.Empty;
    public string CleanName
    {
        get => mCleanName;
        set { mCleanName = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works by removing the 'd'. I think I got the d there by autocomplete accidentally.